# ionic - Google Maps marker not showing up

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

I am trying to add a marker onto the map on loading the page, but it seems that the marker doesn't show up at all.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  Marker,
  GoogleMapsAnimation,
  MyLocation
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: GoogleMap;
  private markers = [];
  records = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public geolocation: Geolocation) { }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }
  loadMap() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(position => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    });

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.3010626054202958, 103.85411771659146);
    this.addMarker(latLng);
  }
  addMarker(latLng) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
    });

    let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";
    this.markers.push(marker);
    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
    marker.setMap(this.map);
  }
  addInfoWindow(marker, content) {
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
      infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

  }
}
```

EDIT: **home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Google Map - Ionic 3
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Adding console.log(this.markers) after this.addMarker(latLng) shows that the marker is instantiated and added into the markers array successfully

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: show your HTML TEMPLATE

Comment: @Sajeetharan updated

Answer (score 0):

This can be a change detection issue: your markers values are there but Angular doesn't know about those and won't trigger template change. Try doing the below and if this won't help possible the culprit is elsewhere but at least you will eliminate CDR issue. It occurs often since location data can be getting into your code without Angular's attention...

Try importing CDR into your component:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
```

Then inject it into constructor:

```
constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, ...
)
```

Then try using detectChanges method after all data was updated:

```
addMarker(latLng) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
    });
    let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";
    this.markers.push(marker);
    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
    marker.setMap(this.map);
    // here try cdr:
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }
```